# jruby: does enabling jruby.thread.pool.enabled means that multiple ruby threads will share same java thread

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading, jruby

We are playing with jruby and option `jruby.thread.pool.enabled`
It that option is enabled and j`ruby.thread.pool.max` is set to a small value, does if  mean that multiple ruby threads will share the same java thread?

In short does enabling `jruby.thread.pool.enabled` means that two or jruby threads might be executed by same java thread?

Answer (score 0):

yes the Java thread might get re-used to serve multipe Ruby threads.

**but not at the same time** ... Ruby threads shouldn't notice anything except if they use "native" Java thread-locals.

I am not sure it's still supported in JRuby 9K.
even on JRuby 1.7 it might not have much sense for typical Rails apps.